# Primefaces Panelgrid not rendered correctly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hello I am having problems with a Panelgrid.
It's not rendered correctly. The code below should rendered two columns:

```
 <p:panelGrid id="pnl" columns="3"  >
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="Types" />
                <p:selectOneMenu  id="tipifase" value="#{home.t}" 
                            >
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{home.types}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="Step 1"   /> <h:inputText value="#{faseAperta.step1}" />
        <f:verbatim><br /></f:verbatim>
        <h:commandLink  action="#{home.search}" > 
                <h:graphicImage value="images/icosearch.gif" style="{border: 0}" />
                    <h:outputText value="ID field" />
         </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>
        <p:column></p:column>
    </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

Unfortunately

```
<h:commandLink  action="#{home.search}" > 
                    <h:graphicImage value="images/icosearch.gif" style="{border: 0}" />
                        <h:outputText value="ID field" />
             </h:commandLink>
```

is rendered on a new line under the first column. 
I would expect to have thre columns instead. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<f:verbatim><br /></f:verbatim>` tag is taking the place in the third column, and that's why the command link is placed in the first one.

If you remove it, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer has stated, the `<f:verbatim><br /></f:verbatim>` takes the place in the third column. If you which to have your components "stacked vertically", you can always use `h:panelGrid`.

```
<p:column>
  <h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:outputText value="Step 1"   /> <h:inputText value="#{faseAperta.step1}" />
    <h:commandLink  action="#{home.search}" > 
      <h:graphicImage value="images/icosearch.gif" style="{border: 0}" />
        <h:outputText value="ID field" />
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:panelGrid>
</p:column>
```